# Android tabcontent contains scrollview which hides content behind tabs

Tags: android, scrollview, android-tabhost

I have a layout which contains a Tabhost. The tabs are at the bottom of the screen. The first tab starts an ActivityGroup. The first activity in that ActivityGroup contains a scrollview. When the contents are displayed in the scrollview and you scroll all the way down, the bottom of the scrollview is hidden behind the tabs. Any ideas how to fix this?

When I start the activitygroup, I use this code:

```
Window window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(pActivityClass.getName(), intent);
setContentView(window.getDecorView());
```

Is the decor view the entire screen? I just want the view to be the tabcontent.
Here is the main layout:

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Here is the view I want in the tabcontent:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/myScrollView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/myLayout" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

        ... a bunch of other components ...

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 4):

Fix your layout so the content view fits above the tab widget, instead of filling the entire parent container, which tells it to lay out as the full size of the `RelativeLayout` and then lay the `TabWidget` on top.  Something more like this:

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs"/>
  <TabWidget
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

I also removed some of the unnecessary items like `android:orientation` which does nothing inside of a `RelativeLayout`.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Optimal result.

*android:minWidth=* Increase the value of...

---

```
    <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:scrollbars="none" >

            <TabWidget
                **android:minWidth="480dp"**
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            </TabWidget>

            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<FrameLayout
android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs"/>
```

Here, the key line is,

```
android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs"
```

Answer (score 0):

I know there might be a "correct" way to do this, but I just added

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"></LinearLayout>
```

to the bottom of the xml file I was loading into the tab.

Also user1060374 is right the FrameLayout needs to be above the Tabwidget or the scrollview will hide(be on top of) the tabbar if the contents needs scrolled.
But just doing this won't answer your question, so I added the padding.